# Binary Array Operations

Tags: matrices

I have two binary arrays like the below image. [image]

Now Array 1 has 2 pairs of blue colored bits. We can get 16 different version of "Array 1" for various combinations of these 4 bits. However, I want to filter only the ones where both bits of any pair are one (like the arrays on the left side of the sample diagram). How can I do that using just Array 1 and Array 2? I have trying to use bit-wise operations (like- AND, OR etc) but failed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: not quite understood

Comment: HI @Agawa001, thanks for commenting. Say, you have a binary array of 4 bits. Now you are told that you can change the 3rd and 4th bit only to make different arrays. You can make 3rd bit '1' and 4th bit '0' while keeping 1st and 2nd bit unchanged. Similarly u can make other combinations. However, only restriction is both bit cant be '1' together. So, you have to find that combination where both 3rd and 4th bit are '1'. Array 2 here just indicates which 2 bit cant be '1' together.

Comment: So the question is the number of combinations of the array 1 in which any one pair containing blue bits has both 1s?

Comment: right. I cant have a Array 1 which contains both '1' in either of the blue pairs.

Comment: So to cross the t's here, what you want is a number of right combinations, which means how do we get 7 without bruteforcing?

Comment: @Agawa001, I did not understand your comment completely. The question is: For the given picture, how can I find the right combinations (there are 9 right combinations) out of all possible 16 combinations?

Comment: @jhon_wick i could count em to 7 :S

Comment: yes, the 7 combinations I have given in the picture are the wrong ones as they have pairs which contains both '1' bits. but there are 9 others possible combinations too which i did not give in the picture. and I want to filter the right ones from the wrong ones.

Comment: if the question asks about **a number** this is quite easy, $S=3^n$ where $n$ is number of pairs, in this case n=2 and $S=3^2$

Comment: does it satisfy your needs ? please respond.

Comment: Not quite but I have solved it in a complete different approach. However, thank u for your answer. I could not select ur answer as it is written in comment. thanks again.